# How to Get Seleted Value from each on dropdown list

Tags: each

I want to change every drop-down list into span with the text that is selected.
How shall I do this?

**My Code:**

```
   $.each($("#ShowFormResult select"), function (i, val) 
   {
   $(this).replaceWith("<span>" + $(this + " option:selected").text() + "</span>");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.each    ($    ("#ShowFormResult select"),     function    (i, val) 
   {
   $(this).replaceWith(""     +     $(this + " option:selected").text()    +    "");
   });